# CNN for image classification, new image representation as input

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, image-processing

i'm trying to classify image pattern with CNN; I started to optimize a neural network with image represented in cartesian coordinate. If I use image represented in polar coordinate should i totaly change my neural network?

Since my image will have the same size, but characteristic will change (for exemple density in an area of the image will change for a given pattern in the new representation)

Comment: What do you means by in polar coordinates? Can you show example

Answer (score 0):

Whenever the data distribution changes, you need to retrain your neural network. However it could very well be that you can keep the same model architecture. You can also try to keep the existing weights from the old data (transfer learning), it might perform better than training from scratch. Or it can be worse.